# Visualization libraries for rendering 3D GIS world on iOS/Android

Tags: 3d, visualisation, mobile, android, ios

Are there any good 3D libraries/frameworks for rendering 3D worlds in geospatial coordinates on mobile platforms?

Use case: I have some known 3D geospatial features (eg. buildings) with their corresponding lat,long,elevation values as well as an underlying DEM. I would like to render such a "scene" from a given camera viewpoint on either an iOS or an Android device.

I could use opengl-es but it would take some effort to convert the geospatial coordinates to cartesian coordinates. Is there a "geospatial-aware" soft of 3D library for mobile platforms that I could use? Something like the AGI insight3D libraries but for mobile.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to develop or use an app? - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jarodyv.lwp.globe&hl=en is one 3D Visualisation Globe for Android

Comment: @Mapperz thanks, but I am actually looking to develop an app.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good website [here](http://mobilegameengines.com/android/3d_game_engines) that lists the ever expanding set of 3D rendering libraries for Android. I can't speak to the quality of any of them as I've only ever used JMonkeyEngine very briefly. They do have a range of target platforms (including Android obviously) and are based on various languages including C/C++, Java, and JavaScript. The other option to consider is one of the many HTML5 solutions, which has the advantage of being cross-platform with the disadvantage of usually incurring a performance penalty (although this seems to be in a constant state of flux).